# "exists" keyword in Python?

Tags: python

I've recently made the following example for Pythons for ... else:

```
def isPrime(element):
    """ just a helper function! don't get religious about it! """
    if element == 2:
        return True
    elif element <= 1 or element % 2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        for i in xrange(3, element, 2):
            print i
            if element % i == 0:
                return False
    return True


myList = [4, 4, 9, 12]

for element in myList:
    if isPrime(element):
        break
else:
    print("The list did not contain a prime.")
```

A fellow student told me, that this task can be done with Scala like this:

```
List(4, 4, 9, 12) exists isPrime
```

Which gets lazy evaluated.

Does something similar like the exists-keyword exist in Python? Or is there a PEP for that?

Comment: You probably want to check that `element == 2` before `element % 2 == 0`; the latter is always true when the former is true.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it. But that is only an example to make a scenario where it could be used.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
myList = [4, 4, 9, 12]

if not any(isPrime(x) for x in myList):
    print("The list did not contain a prime")
```

Python also has `all()` which cranks through any sequence and returns `True` if all elements evaluate true.

`any()` and `all()` both have short-circuit evaluation: if `any()` finds any element that evaluates true, it stops and returns `True`; and if `all()` finds any element that evaluates false, it stops and returns `False`.

Both are "lazy" in that they use Python iteration to pull values one at a time.  For example:

```
import random
def rand_sequence(n_max):
    while True:
        next_random = random.randint(0, n_max)
        print(next_random)
        yield next_random

all(isPrime(x) for x in rand_sequence(20))
```

This will iterate until a non-prime number is found, then return `False`.  It prints the numbers as a side-effect so you can watch it work.  I just tried this and got:

```
17
3
0
```

P.S. I went to a talk at a Python conference, and the speaker mentioned that he commonly uses `any()` as a very efficient way to do a loop.  A `for` loop re-binds the loop variable for each loop, but `any()` doesn't do that; it just keeps checking values.  So if you use `any()` with a function that always returns `None` or a false value, it will iterate its way all to the end of the sequence, and according to that guy, it's the fastest way in Python to do it.  (And if your function returns a value that is not `None` and isn't false, you can use `all()` for the same trick.  The only time it doesn't work is if sometimes the function returns a true value and sometimes it returns a false value.  But you can force it to always work:

```
any(my_function(x) and False for x in sequence)
```

P.P.S. Let's use `all()` to rewrite `isPrime()`!  I'll change the name to `is_prime()` to conform to PEP 8.  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

```
def is_prime(element):
    """ just a helper function! don't get religious about it! """
    if element == 2:
        return True
    elif element <= 1 or element % 2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return all(element % i for i in xrange(3, element, 2))
```

Comment: I didn't realize `any` and `all` short-circuited! Great.

Comment: Yes, the short-circuit behavior is the big advantage over using `reduce()` with a logical AND or logical OR operator.

Comment: Note that while both short-circuit, the laziness in the expression is provided by using a generator expression.

Comment: Well, if the Python developers were really stupid, `any()` and `all()` could call `list()` on the iterator, and then it wouldn't be lazy anymore.  Using the Python iterator interface makes a function lazy, IMHO.  (If the Python developers were that stupid, my `rand_sequence()` example would blow up because that generator will run forever if you let it; note the `while True:` loop.)  Of course some functions *can't* be lazy; `sorted()` comes to mind.  Try `x = sorted(rand_sequence(20))` and watch the side-effect print numbers fly.  You don't even need to evaluate the iterator.

Answer (score -1):

```
[x for x in myList if isPrime(x)]
```

Comment: This just a list comprehension, not short-circuit behavior

Comment: Code-only answers usually don't explain anything. I'd recommend adding an explanation in the near future, so this post doesn't get downvoted more.