# Finding the number of words with all vowels

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am given a text file that is stored in a list called `words_list`:

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
    words_file = open('words.txt')

    words_list = []
    for w in words_file:
        w = w.strip().strip('\n')
        words_list.append(w)
```

That's what the list of strings look like (it's a really, really long list of words)

I have to find "all the words" with all of the vowels; so far I have:

```
def all_vowel(words_list):
    count = 0
    for w in words_list:
        if all_five_vowels(w):   # this function just returns true
            count = count + 1
    if count == 0
        print '<None found>'
    else 
        print count
```

The problem with this is that `count` adds 1 every time it sees a vowel, whereas I want it to add 1 *only* if the *entire word* has all of the vowels.

Comment: After `.strip()`, `.strip('\n')` is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the word_list variable is an actual list, probably your "all_five_vowels" function is wrong.

This could be an alternative implementation:

```
def all_five_vowels(word):
    vowels = ['a','e','o','i','u']
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            vowels.remove(letter)
            if len(vowels) == 0:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Can you explain how the vowels.remove(letter) works ... in an instance I have the words: aaah   and    alladin

Comment: In this case, vowels is a list. So the way vowels.remove(letter) works, is that the letter element will be removed from the list vowels  if the letter is in the list. If all vowels are present in your word, all vowels will be removed from this list, giving the list a length of 0.
If you input 'alladin', the list will result in ['e','o','u'], having a length of more than 0, returning False.

Answer (score 6):

Simply test if any of your words are a subset of the vowels set:

```
vowels = set('aeiou')

with open('words.txt') as words_file:
    for word in words_file:
        word = word.strip()
        if vowels.issubset(word):
            print word
```

[`set.issubset()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) works on any sequence (including strings):

```
>>> set('aeiou').issubset('word')
False
>>> set('aeiou').issubset('education')
True
```

Comment: I think this will be much more computationally efficient than the other solution

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Peters has already posted a solution that is probably the fastest solution in Python.  For completeness, here is another good way to solve this in Python:

```
vowels = set('aeiou')

with open('words.txt') as words_file:
    for word in words_file:
        word = word.strip()
        if all(ch in vowels for ch in word):
            print word
```

This uses the built-in function `all()` with a generator expression, and it's a handy pattern to learn.  This reads as "if all the characters in the word are vowels, print the word."  Python also has `any()` which could be used for checks like "if any character in the word is a vowel, print the word".

More discussion of `any()` and `all()` here:  ["exists" keyword in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958874/exists-keyword-in-python/10958885#10958885)